# How do I add CDATA to an xml file?

Tags: html, xml, xml-parsing, cdata

I have an existing xml file that holds notifications I want to display on my site. A snippet follows:

```
<contents>
  <item>
    <![CDATA[
        <a style="font-weight: bold;" href="http://engadget.com">Engadget</a>
    ]]>
  </item>
  <item>
    <![CDATA[
        <a style="font-weight: bold;" href="http://cnn.com">CNN</a>
    ]]>
  </item>
</contents>
```

I'm trying to open this document and add new "items" to it, but I can't:

```
        foreach (string s in notifications)
        {
            XmlElement newElement = doc.CreateElement("item");
            newElement.InnerXml = "&lt;![CDATA[ " + s + " ]]>";
            doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("/contents")[0].AppendChild(newElement);
        }
```

notifications is a List that I'm using to store the links. The error I'm getting is:

*']]>' is not allowed in character data.*

The notifications need to contain HTML, because of the way I'm displaying it. Thanks for looking, guys.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using

```
newElement.AppendChild(doc.CreateCDataSection(s));
```

instead of

```
newElement.InnerXml = "&lt;![CDATA[ " + s + " ]]>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
newElement.InnerXml = "&lt;![CDATA[ " + s + " ]]&gt;";
```