# How to add CDATA in XML using Spark XML library

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

I am using Spark 2.2 XML library to write data in XML format. But i want add CDATA to every value in XML like below.

```
<RECORD>
<PROP NAME="processingTime">
<PVAL>
<![CDATA[ 1499713726138 ]]>
</PVAL>
</PROP>
<PROP NAME="isActive">
<PVAL>
<![CDATA[ true ]]>
</PVAL>
</PROP>
<PROP NAME="lineOfBusiness">
<PVAL>
<![CDATA[ abc ]]>
</PVAL>
</PROP>
<PROP NAME="language">
<PVAL>
<![CDATA[ EN ]]>
</PVAL>
</PROP>
<PROP NAME="language">
<PVAL>
<![CDATA[ FR ]]>
</PVAL>
</PROP>
</RECORD>
```

Can someone suggest me how to do this in Spark Java?.Thx

Comment: *"i want add CDATA to every value"* Why? It just makes the XML bigger, for no reason whatsoever. None of the shown values even has any special characters that would benefit from use of `CDATA`. And no XML processor should ever care whether text is in a `CDATA` or not. The processed text should always end up the same. `CDATA` is simple a special encoding that eliminates the need to use `&lt;`, `&gt;`, and `&amp;` entities, making the XML simpler if there are a lot of them.

Comment: You can check This post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9473667/how-do-i-add-cdata-to-an-xml-file. this will help you.

Comment: yeah. in provided XML, we don't have special characters. However, i have lot other fields which had special characters. So there i need CDATA.

Comment: We are not using any java xml library to use newElement.InnerXml to add CDATA. So is there any approach to do it Spark xml library?.

Comment: Hey @Sekhar Did You find the solution for this ?
I have a similar problem Spark is not giving me CDATA string.